# Credit Memo Adjustment Fee Woes

Tags: magento-1.7, creditmemo

I've experienced this issue with Magento for a very long time.

When applying an adjustment fee to a credit memo, I have to do the following

1. Configure `Qty to Refund` accordingly
2. Fill in the Adjustment Fee
3. Click `Update Qtys` (at which point the Grand total is updated)
4. Fill in the Adjustment Fee again (even though the Grand total is correct)
5. Click Refund

My question is as follows:

- If I don't fill in the Adjustment Fee the second time, it isn't applied (the Adjustment fee value **needs to be in the textfield** when I click Refund, otherwise even though it is reflected in the grand total, it isn't applied when the credit memo is created & then the grand total is different on the created credit memo.

Why is this the case?